# Stubbing 3rd party url from 3rd party jar?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, wiremock

While writing junits we dont want to hit the external apis cause if they are down our build will fail or any other reason. I am using a third party jar which calls some external api(end point). Can i stub that endpoint while running my junits using mockito/wiremock/powermock ?

Answer (score -1):

I've only used Mockito, but have found it to be really good for stubbing in JUnit - it has a really easy syntax to stub your methods that call endpoints that allows you to say "when I am calling [endpoint] I expect [response] to be returned" using "when" and "thenReturn" methods, eg.

```
int USER_ID = 5;    
when(userIDFinder.find(userInformation)).thenReturn(USER_ID);
```

So when my userIDFinder.find(x) method is called during the test the method returns 5 instead of calling to the endpoint.

Comment: That is good for the methods which we call directly from our code. The method from which external endpoint is being called is very nested inside the external jar. It can surely be done using mockito but very complex and so many mocking. So looking for better approach